# Change Fragment from fragment, next fragment must have Back button in android, How to do this?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using sliding menu in andorid, when i click on slide menu's list item, that time i can change **fragment-A**, and now my question is that One **Button-A** in **Fragment-A**, i want to change another **Fragment-B** on **Button-A** click listener, **Fragment-B** must have **default back button on Actionbar**, when press on Default Back button it goes to the **Fragment-A**, How to do this?

I am using this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, My_Fragment_B_Object).commit();
getSlidingMenu().showContent();
```

// Fragment B class Code:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, container, false);
        ((FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: By "back", do you mean "up"? (i.e. a left-pointing arrow next to the home icon). If so, try adding a call to `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Are both Fragments hosted on one Activity?

Comment: You will hve to maintain a stack n in on back press pop the fragmnt.